# What exponent law have I violated?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Given the expression: $b^8(2b)^4$, simplify it.

I multiply $b^8$ and $2b$, which gives $(2b^9)^4.$

$(2b^9)^4 = 16b^{36}$. However this is incorrect.

The correct answer is to distribute the exponent first like so:
$b^8(2^4b^4) = 16b^{12}$. This makes sense, but I'd like to know why my original approach was incorrect.

Comment: Parenthesis are important.

Comment: @ZacharySelk: Parenthesis *is* important. ParenthesEs are important :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have violated the **order of operations**.  $b^8 (2b)^4$ means that $2b$ is raised to the fourth power, then multiplied by $b^8$.  If you were to perform multiplication of $b^8$ by $2b$ before you raise to the fourth power, you would also have raised $b^8$ to the fourth power, resulting in an additional factor of $b^{24}$.  As you can see, $36 = 24 + 12$.

---

To illustrate how one might have written the expression to obtain your erroneous result, we would write instead $(b^8 (2b))^4 = 16b^{36}$.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, it's less that you violated a specific exponent property, more that you used one that doesn't exist.

The two most relevant exponent properties are that

- $a^m \cdot a^n = a^{m + n}$; if you are multiplying two powers **of the same base**, you can add the exponents together. Or,
- $a^n \cdot b^n = (a \cdot b)^n$; if you are multiplying two expressions **raised to the same power**, you can perform the multiplication first and then raise to that power (actually, on second thought, this is essentially the property you violated).

But $b^8(2b)^4$ is neither of those things: It's a product of $b^8$ and $(2b)^4$:

- They don't have the same base ($b$ vs. $2b$), so the first property doesn't apply.
- They're not being raised to the same exponent ($8$ vs $4$), so the second property doesn't apply.

Comment: You might also mention that you could write b^8 as b^2^4 to get terms raised to the same power.

Answer (score 2):

The point of the parentheses is that you are only applying the exponent ${}^4$ to the $2b$, inside the parentheses, not to the $b^8$ outside. Thus, we would apply the power to the parenthesis first, then evaluate the product.

Answer (score 2):

$b^8(2b)^4$ is where you started.  Then you moved the $b^8$ inside.  However, to do this you have to compensate that inside the parens everything is raised to the 4th power, so you need to divide the exponent of $b$ by 4:

$b^8(2b)^4 = (b^2 \times 2b)^4 = (2b^3)^4$.  Leaving the exponent unchanged when brought into the parentheses caused your error.

As an exercise: what is $r$ equal to in this equation: $x^9 = (x^r)^3$?

Answer (score -1):

If you pull the $b^8$ inside the parentheses, you need to reduce the exponent, because by putting it inside the parentheses, you are raising it to the $4th$ power:
$$b^8(2b)^4 = (2b^3)^4 = 2^4b^{12} = 16b^{12}.$$
Alternatively, you could distribute the exponent to the $2b$ before multiplying in the $b^8$: 
$$b^8(2b)^4 = b^82^4b^4 = 2^4b^{12} = 16b^{12}.$$

Answer (score -3):

$b^8(2b)=2b^9$, $b^8(2b)^4=b^82^4b^4=16b^{12}$.